# How to compare pair of two columns with another pair of column of a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe below.I want to compare pairs of two columns with another pairs of two columns. Every time The comparison of pairs of column should be based on comparing the entries of columns 1:2 with the entries of column 2:1.  And where these two column pair is being matched then i want the frequency count to be added with that pair of column.

```
z <- c(3,3,2)
y <- c(1,2,3)
x <- data.frame(y,z)
library(plyr)
fr <- count(x[,1:2])
fr
# The matched pair of 1:2 with 2:1
fr[3,1:2] == fr[2,2:1]
```

My desired output is the dataframe that contains the sum of frequency count of the matched pair.

```
  y z freq
1 1 3    1
2 2 3    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`.  We `transform` the dataset by changing the 'x' column with the minimum value of 'y' and 'z' for each row (using `pmin`),  'z' with the maximum value of 'y' and 'z' for each row (using `pmax`), create a new column of 'freq' with 1 as value.  Then, use `xtabs` to get the `sum` of the 'freq' by 'x' and 'y' (by default, `xtabs` gets the `sum`), and convert to `data.frame` (`as.data.frame`).

```
 as.data.frame(xtabs(freq~., transform(x, y= pmin(y,z),
               z= pmax(y,z), freq=1)))
 #  y z Freq
 #1 1 3    1
 #2 2 3    2
```

---

Or another option would to loop along the rows with `apply` using `MARGIN=1`, `sort` the elements and `aggregate` to get the `sum` grouped by 'y' and 'z'

```
x[] <- t(apply(x, 1, sort))
aggregate(Freq~., transform(x, Freq=1), sum)
#    y z Freq
#1 1 3    1
#2 2 3    2
```

Comment: Is there any other simple way of doing it.? I am not an expert in r i have no knowledge about this functions xtabs,pmax,pmin etc. Isn't it posiible with the identical function.?

Comment: @jaspsingh  Updated with another option.  Hope it is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks. It is easier. Can you please tell how the frequency count is being calculated without using count..?

Comment: @jaspsingh It is calculated by creating a column of 1s and group by the existing columns 'y' and 'z'.  So, if there are 2 1s in the `2 3` category, the `sum` will be 1+1 =2